# Laravel 4 model method failed with "Call to undefined method"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My models extends "\BaseModel" which in its turn extends the Eloquent.

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

public function foo($attribute)
{
    //some code
}
```

In my collection, where the model being instanced I'm trying to access the "foo()" method, but it responses me with "Call to undefined method".

```
$data = IncomeDoc::with('details')
                            ->where('type', '!=', 2)
                            ->get(); 
$data = $data->foo();
```

Moreover, I tried to place the method "foo" in the model itself, but there was no difference.

Thanks for all

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you populate `$data` it becomes a symphony db object and is no longer your model

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for the info. do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @SheikhHeera i'm trying to manipulate my data to achive this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802670/laravel-4-eager-load-as-a-list-of-ids)

Answer (score 0):

Basically `get()` method returns a Collection of instances. Assume more than 1 model satisfy `type != 2` condition. If you want to get first model under the condition just use `first()` instead.

```
$data = IncomeDoc::with('details')
                        ->where('type', '!=', 2)
                        ->first(); 
$data = $data->foo();
```

Otherwise:

```
$collection = IncomeDoc::with('details')
                        ->where('type', '!=', 2)
                        ->get(); 

$data = [];
foreach($collection as $item) {
    $data[] = $data->foo();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i have tried this, and it does work but responses me with only one result.

Comment: Sure. Otherwise you need to iterate through the collection.

Comment: maybe do you have any idea how could i achive [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22802670/laravel-4-eager-load-as-a-list-of-ids)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `get()` returns a collection, an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and in this collection there is no `foo` method but to call the method that you declared in your model, you need to access the model, so first model in the collection would be `0` and to get it you may use `$data->first()` or `$data->get(0)`, to get the second item (model) from the collection you may use `$data->get(1)` and so on but you may also use a `loop`, for example:

```
$data = IncomeDoc::with('details')->where('type', '!=', 2)->get();
$dataArray = array();
$data->each(function($item) use (&$dataArray){
    $dataArray[] = $item->foo();
});
return View::make('viewname')->with('data', $dataArray);
```

Also, you may directly pass the `$data` to your view and can apply the function call from the view within a loop but not recommended.